# How to make one row to have the same color in a table

Tags: tables

I'm making a table, which has zebra colors. but I'm facing a problem that the gray cell looks not homogeneous like the image illustrates. here is my code:

```
\newcolumntype{g}{>{\columncolor{Gray}}c}
\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{6cm}|p{10cm}|}
\hline
\rowcolor{white}
\thead{Example} & \thead{Example}\\
\hline
\rowcolor{Gray}
Example1 & bla\\
\rowcolor{Gray}
& bla\\ 
\rowcolor{Gray}
& bla\\
\hline
\rowcolor{white}
Example1 & bla\\
& bla\\
& bla\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image: see the pic]
what should I do to avoid this?
thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Do you speak of the thin horizontal white lines in the gray panel?

Comment: yes I'm talking about these small Lines

Comment: At the end of each Gray row, use `\\[-0.2pt]` instead of a plain  \\.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `nicematrix` provides an environment `{NiceTabular}` with tools which have been designed to avoid these thin white lines (which appear in some PDF viewers which use the PDF renderer MuPDF and PDF.js: SumatraPDF, Firefox, DropBox, Papeeria, etc.).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{makecell} % for \thead

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{|p{6cm}|p{5cm}|}[color-inside]
\Hline
\thead{Example} & \thead{Example}\\
\Hline
\rowcolor{LightGray}
Example1 & bla\\
\rowcolor{LightGray}
& bla\\ 
\rowcolor{LightGray}
& bla\\
\Hline
Example1 & bla\\
& bla\\
& bla\\
\Hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

There are syntactical variants.

For example, you can specify with `\RowStyle` that you want the next three rows to have a background.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{makecell} % for \thead

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{|p{6cm}|p{5cm}|}[color-inside]
\Hline
\thead{Example} & \thead{Example}\\
\Hline
\RowStyle[nb-rows=3,rowcolor=LightGray]{}
Example1 & bla\\
& bla\\ 
& bla\\
\Hline
Example1 & bla\\
& bla\\
& bla\\
\Hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You can also put an instruction `\rowlistcolors{LightGray}` to start coloring and put `\rowlistcolors{}` to stop the coloring.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{makecell} % for \thead

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{|p{6cm}|p{5cm}|}[color-inside]
\Hline
\thead{Example} & \thead{Example}\\
\Hline
\rowlistcolors{LightGray}
Example1 & bla\\
& bla\\ 
& bla\\
\Hline
\rowlistcolors{}
Example1 & bla\\
& bla\\
& bla\\
\Hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

It's also possible to put the coloring instructions outside the tabular itself (in the so-called `\CodeBefore` provided by `nicematrix`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{makecell} % for \thead

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{|p{6cm}|p{5cm}|}
\CodeBefore
    \rowcolor{LightGray}{2-4}
\Body
    \Hline
    \thead{Example} & \thead{Example}\\
    \Hline
    Example1 & bla\\
    & bla\\ 
    & bla\\
    \Hline
    Example1 & bla\\
    & bla\\
    & bla\\
    \Hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The output is always the same.

Comment: thanks a lot. I'm facing right now this error :Package nicematrix Error: The option 'colortbl-like' is unknown for the

Comment: You probably don't have the latest version of `nicematrix`. You should update your TeX installation. If you use Overleaf, you have to upload in the repertory of your project the latest version of the file `nicematrix.sty`. You can find that file on the SVN server of TeXLive: `www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty`

Comment: thanks a lot for helping